# Не понимаю как работает eventObject

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу чтоб он мне вернул на какой элемент я нажал, а по итогу выводит `undefined`:

```
$('#div_for_img img').click(function(eventObject) {
   var a = eventObject.shift;
   alert(a); 
    });
```

P.S. Какой версией `jQuery` лучше всего пользоваться/обучаться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Объект события](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) не имеет никакого отношения к JQuery, для его понимания надо изучать чистый JS. В данном случае Вы пытаетесь получить свойство объекта под названием `shift`, но такого свойства у него нет. Вот он и выводит Вам `undefined` в качестве значения.

Для получения элемента, на который вы нажали, используется свойство `target`.

Даже без JQuery:

```js
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

```html
<div id="clickMe">Click Me</div>
```

Единственное отличие, в JQuery он будет работать вместе с IE, когда как в чистом JS надо проделать некоторые дополнительные шаги. Обучатся лучше на самой последней версии или на той, для какой написаны Ваши материалы по которым обучаетесь и хорошо если они будут хотя бы для 2.7 или выше. Главное что бы не для первой, она уже достаточно стара.

P.S. Ссылочку на [справку MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) сохраните, она Вам пригодится еще не раз.